# Couldn't find User with 'id'=admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have followed Hartl's tutorial to make a ToDoList with a tagging system, also with the help of this [word guide](https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBa2qs9CFZQ). While improvising for the difference in code, this error in my `development.log` showed up. There is a separate page that will show the administrator users.

development.log

```
Started GET "/users/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-26 18:55:57 +0800
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"admin"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=admin):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `show'
```

Here's my controller code:

MicropostsController

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy


  def index
    @microposts = current_user.microposts
    @microposts = @microposts.tagged_with(params[:tag]) if params[:tag]
  end


  def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "You have deleted a task!"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :tag_list, :tag, 
        {tag_ids: [] }, :tag_ids)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if (@user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]))
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome back, #{@user.name}!"
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_back_or root_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

StaticPagesController

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @new_micropost = Micropost.new
      @feed_items = current_user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page]) 
    end 
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
     log_in @user
     flash[:info] = "Welcome to the to-do app, #{@user.name}"
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'
   end
  end

  def admin
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    a = User.find(params[:id]).name
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "#{a} has been deleted!"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

 def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile for @user.name has been updated"
    redirect_to(@user)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Update Failed."
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                  :password_confirmation, :admin)
    end
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "You are not logged in. Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if !current_user?(@user)
        flash[:danger] = "You are not authorized to visit this page."
        redirect_to(root_url)
      end
    end
  end
```

Config/routes.rb and running `rake routes`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :microposts          

  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post    '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',    to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',    to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',   to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get   '/users/admin',     to: 'users#admin'

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'microposts#index', as: :tag

  root   'static_pages#home'
end

        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
         users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
    microposts GET    /microposts(.:format)          microposts#index
               POST   /microposts(.:format)          microposts#create
 new_micropost GET    /microposts/new(.:format)      microposts#new
edit_micropost GET    /microposts/:id/edit(.:format) microposts#edit
     micropost GET    /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#show
               PATCH  /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#update
               PUT    /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#update
               DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#destroy
         about GET    /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
       contact GET    /contact(.:format)             static_pages#contact
        signup GET    /signup(.:format)              users#new
               POST   /signup(.:format)              users#create
         login GET    /login(.:format)               sessions#new
               POST   /login(.:format)               sessions#create
        logout DELETE /logout(.:format)              sessions#destroy
   users_admin GET    /users/admin(.:format)         users#admin
           tag GET    /tags/:tag(.:format)           microposts#index
          root GET    /                              static_pages#home
```

Does anyone have any clue how to solve the problem? Do inform me if more information is needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What calls this link? `GET "/users/admin" `

Comment: There are actually views for an `admin.html.erb` and `header.html.erb`, but I don't think I will be showing it as it seems that the problem has been solved by the answer. Just waiting for maybe a slight explanation before I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the following line in your `routes.rb`.

```
get   '/users/admin',     to: 'users#admin'
```

above

```
resources :users
```

The problem you got is that Rails routing system recognizes this path - `/users/admin` as matching to `/users/:id` and therefore routes to `users#show` action.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know the order matters. Is there a method to deduce how Rails recognises paths?

Comment: Not directly, but you can test your routes with rspec:
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. Do you mind looking at another question of mine when you're available?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367340/tagging-system-not-filtering-according-to-tutorial